# In Unity (2017) is there a way to set the buttons used by Input.GetAxis() programatically?

Tags: unity, input, ui-design

The buttons used for keyboard axis inputs can be set manually via Negative and Positive Button fields for the axis at Edit > Project Settings > Input Manager. However I'd like to make this a user configurable option which I think means needing to set the button values from a script.

I've been looking for a method along the lines of:

`Input.SetAxis("Vertical").positveButton`

But so far I'm striking out. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Just a quick question before we go any further: Why do you want to/have to do this?

Comment: @Bálint - a few reasons: 1) it seems nice to give the user their choice of input keys; 2) it would make it easier to experiment with the input key mappings on complex games that are being played or developed on a standard keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

## No it is not possible.

I recommend getting the [Rewired asset](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/rewired-21676) instead. There may be other assets that also work, but I know Rewired is already set up to allow rebinding for both mouse/keyboard and controllers.